# Order by multiple meta keys on wordpress

Tags: wp-query, loop, order

After multiple research I didn't find the correct answer to my question.

I just need to order my custom post type by date and then by time (format: 18:00).

Here's what I tried: http://pastebin.com/BRR6h08j

It orders well by the date but not by the time. And I don't need to hide events that occured.

If someone can help me getting my correct meta_keys

I know the problem is here:

```
'meta_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'heure_de_lartiste',
        'value' => $todaysDate,
        'compare' => '>='
       )
  ),
```

I don't know what to put in "value" and "compare"

Thanks a lot,

Jhon

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why can't you use the `post_date` of the `custom post type` which includes date and time together?

```
 $arg = array(  
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'orderby' => 'post_date', 
    'order' => 'DESC')
 $result = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuz it is not the post_date I want to show but my meta_key called 'heure_de_lartiste' that are not the same !